# Is possible to double the cube with unmarked T-shaped ruler and compass?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, galois-theory, geometric-construction

As Galois depicted, cube doublication cannot be constructed via unmarked straightedge and compass. Any solution to this problem should make cubic extension or above. I have already known this method to construct any angle trisection via unmarked T-shaped ruler and compass:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#With_a_right_triangular_ruler
where T-shaped ruler is this, or you can use set square instead:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-square

But I cannot find a way to construct an conchoid of a straightline as neusis construction do:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube#Using_a_marked_ruler

I know only one special technique to use unmarked T-shaped ruler: one arm passes through one given point P, another arm keeps tangent to one point Q on given curve C. Moving point Q, so the right angle of T-shaped ruler O can draw a curve. I think this curve fits this difination:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_curve

I have proved the conchoid of a circle if given point P is on circle constructed by neusis construction is equal to curve drawed by unmarked T-shaped ruler on a circle with the technique above. But I still cannot find a way to doublication the cube.

There is a proof for not constructing that length via angle trisector:
http://math.fau.edu/yiu/PSRM2015/yiu/New%20Folder%20(4)/Downloaded%20Papers/AMMGleason1988.pdf
but I believe that unmarked T-shaped ruler is much more than angle trisector.

But is it possible? If possible, how can I draw it?